# How to decompose a square symmetric matrix into two diagonalizable matrices provided that one of them is the transpose of the other?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let`s have a square symmetric matrix A, and I wish to decompose it into two diagonalizable matrices so that:
$$A=M^TM$$
where,
$$M$$ and $$M^T$$ are; a diagonalizable matrix and its transpose.
First, I tried decomposing A using PCA (principle component analysis);
$$A=V\sigma V^T$$
This gives column vectors V and their corresponding eigen values.
But then I can not be able to solve for M using Singular value Decomposition  (SVD) because I do not have U:
$$M=U\sqrt\sigma V^T$$ 
So what is the way out? Is there any sharp method of obtaining U and hence M or any numerical approximation method instead?
Also I am interested to know whether such decomposition can be applied to any square symmetric matrix in general with no exception?

Comment: Why do you want to decompose $A$ into a product of two non-diagonalizable matrices?

Comment: Symmetric matrices represent inner products via the formula $\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle_A=\mathbf v^TA\mathbf u$. Viewed from this perspective, $M^TM$ is the collection of all scalar products of the set of vectors given by the columns of $M$. That might help you find some candidates for the decomposition.

Comment: 1) To make the matter more sensible and probably easier, I want to decompose the square symmetrix matrix into two diagonalizable matrices as above.

Comment: 2) I dont understand your clue. M is the matrix which is I am looking for which I need to derive it from A.

Comment: I changed the topic title to mean a kind of decomposition into two diagonalizable matrices instead.

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric positive semi-definite, then you can use a [Cholesky factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)

Comment: Will Cholesky method give a unique matrix M?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the way out.
I have mentioned in my first post that I would have calculated M if I had U because,
$$M=U\sqrt\sigma V^T$$
In fact, U itself is an orthonormal matrix which means I can choose an arbitrarily orthonormal matrix and plug it in the SVD equation above to yield M. There are two notes here:
1) M will not be unique.
2) $$M^TM=A$$ which is my original square symmetric matrix because $$U^TU=I$$ 
So steps to decompose a square symmetric matrix A into $$M^TM$$.
1) Decompose the square symmetric matrix using prinicple components analysis.
$$M^TM=V\sigma V^T$$.
2) Use $$V and \sqrt\sigma$$ matrices to construct M.
3) Multiply the matrices in step 2 by U which is an orthonormal matrix to yield;
$$M=U\sqrt\sigma V^T$$. 
Done.

Comment: If you're okay with taking root of $\sigma$, then why not just use $M=V\sqrt{\sigma}V^T$?